# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver id.flutter.flutter_background_service.WatchdogReceiver

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-service

I have an issue. My background function does not work after a while when app goes to background mode. These are error codes we found in Firebase Crashlytics.

```
Plugin => flutter_background_service: ^2.4.6
Flutter Version => 3.10.3
```

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver id.flutter.flutter_background_service.WatchdogReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.name.name.name/id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{499a372 u0a932 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:22933, seq(0,0,0)} at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3612) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)`

`Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.name.name.name/id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{499a372 u0a932 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:22933, seq(0,0,0)} at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1666) at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1611) at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:677) at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:677) at id.flutter.flutter_background_service.WatchdogReceiver.onReceive(:47) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3603) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)`

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Me too - I cannot reproduce and don't know if this is causing crashes for the users or is just silently creating this error